# Jquery Unrecognized Expression selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the  following code which is supposed to select the  value from a select drop down :

```
 $('#edit_condition option[value=' + value.client_status + ']').attr("selected", "selected");
```

The values on the HTML are Care and Not Care as shown below :

```
<select class='form-control condition' required="" name='condition' id='edit_condition'>
                                                            <option value=''> </option>
                                                            <option value='Care'>Care</option>
                                                            <option value='Not Care'>Not Care </option>
                                                        </select>
```

When the  returned value is Care from jquery JSON file , it highlights the value very well but when the  value is Not Care , I get the  following error :

```
jquery-1.10.2.js:1850 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #edit_condition option[value=Not Care]
```

How do I handle the above issue ? / How should I pass my values on JQuery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [**`docs`**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), correct syntax is

```
jQuery( "[attribute='value']" )
```

Hence the line

```
 $('#edit_condition option[value=' + value.client_status + ']')
```

Should be

```
 $('#edit_condition option[value="' + value.client_status + '"]')
```

Value shouls surround by double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery Function it will work.
`$("#edit_condition").val(value.client_status);`